# Conversion from Specific String to JSON

Tags: java, regex, json, parsing

Suppose I have this string:

```
For the AWSDataTransfer product, this is the public pricing plan.

Regarding data transfer across EC2 AZs:
In all AWS regions, inbound is $0.01/GB.
In all AWS regions, outbound is $0.01/GB.
```

I would like to change it to JSON which would be like this:

```
{
    "Product" : "AWSDataTransfer",
    "PlanName" : "public",

    "EC2Regional" : [
        {"region" : "all", "type" : "in", "rate" : "0.01/GB"},
        {"region" : "all", "type" : "out", "rate" : "0.01/GB"}
    ],
}
```

How do I do this using Regular Expressions. Can anyone write the code and help me out.

Comment: This is _probably_ going to require some complex parsing.  Not sure it's suitable to just say: "_hey, give me a regex_".

Comment: sorry but what exactly is the string?

Comment: That seems like an awfully arbitrary string to use...

Answer (score 2):

You could create one or two simple classes containing the fields you describe, e.g.:

```
public class Plan {
    private String product;
    private String planName;
    private List<EC2Regional> ec2Regional;
}

public class EC2Regional {
    private String region;
    private String type;
    private String rate;
}
```

(I've left out getters and setters for readability.)
Then you can use a JSON library like Jackson to serialize it to JSON.

You'd probably want to replace some of the String types with enums or other custom types.

Good luck.

Comment: I think the OP is given a text string and wants to convert it to JSON.

Comment: Actually, how do I transfer my original string to Map-List-String format using a java program?

Comment: @user2464719 - You're going to have to write some substantial code to achieve this. In my opinion, asking somebody to do this for you is beyond the scope of this website... but you're welcome to try.